# What does this icon mean?

Tags: layers

The white arrow in attached image, what does it mean? I use Windows and there is no tool tip with info.

[image]

Comment: Ok, i noticed this scene layer has an animation attached to it. However, i have several layers which use animation but do not contain such a icon. Why have a few scene layers (see above image) such an icon and contain special layer in the the animation view? I remoevd the animation view extra info, but the icon and info in the scene layer is persistent. How can i clean this up?

Answer (score 2):

That small squiggle arrow is indicating that the object has an [action](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Actions). Meaning that the object is animated.
If you click on the plus button and open up the hierarchy you will see that it is an animation.
[image: outliner]

Comment: How can i remove this action, i tried to remove it from the animation view, but the info in the scene layer is still there... i do not want extra actions. Im not aware that i added extra actions.

Comment: David, thanks for additional info, i noticed that too. But teh strange thing is im not aware to have animated these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok to get rid of these icons (which indicate an action), right click it and pick "UNLINK ACTION". Either before this or after open the ANIMATION VIEW -> CLICK the Object and then delete the action from the animation layer too.